# Best way to scroll Firefox with keyboard when focus is on another window?

Tags: linux, firefox, terminal, gnome, wayland

I am runnig Linux with Gnome/Wayland and I mostly use two GUI applications Terminator and Firefox.

I use Terminator fullscreen with transparency and I am able to read pages on Firefox at the same time:

[image]

It would be great to be able to scroll Firefox with the keyboard and keeping the focus to Terminator at the same time.

Do you have any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: On Mac, simply holding the cursor over a window will send the scroll focus to that window, even if inactive. Windows never used to cope with that well, though it got a bit better over time, but I haven't seen Win11. Knowing nix, it will be in one environment manager or another. Though… being able to scroll a window hidden behind another is likely to be a stumbling block - how does it know which window you mean if you cannot differentiate it with the cursor?

Comment: `On Mac, simply holding the cursor over a window will send the scroll focus to that window`.  Yes, but the window is below/hidden by the transparent terminal window.  I doubt very seriously that any GUI is going to have a way to do this.

Comment: Would it be an option to use a drop-down terminal like `guake` or `yakuake` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it, but:

- As said in comments, you can use drop-down terminal like guake or yakuake instead.
- You can do in Firefox:

  1. Press F12 and select `Console`.
  2. Enter this code and press Enter:

```javascript
var pixCount_1 = 0;if(window.scroll) {setInterval(() => {
    window.scroll(0, pixCount_1);
    pixCount_1++;
}, 50)}
```

*In this code you may replace 50 by bigger value. Changing this will change scrolling speed.*